# Mimic Caffe Image Pre-Processing in Tensorflow

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, caffe

I'm working on caffe Tensorflow conversion by using [mmdnn](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn), [caffe-tensorflow](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow) projects.

I can see a huge deviation in the output of each layer. I have some query on Image Pre-Processing procedure between Caffe and Tensorflow. Basically wanna mimic the caffe image pre-processing in tensorflow. So, I can evaluate the layer by layer output.

**Caffe Image Preprocessing steps:**

```py
image = caffe.io.load_image(image_path)
transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data':
net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
transformer.set_transpose('data', (2,0,1))
transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2,1,0)) # the reference model has channels in BGR order instead of RGB
transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255.0) # the reference model operates on images in [0,255] range instead of [0,1]
image = np.asarray([transformer.preprocess('data', image)])
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = image
```

Here, It reads a image and convert RGB to BGR Format and scale the image to [0, 255] from [-1, 1].

**Tensorflow Image Preprocessing steps:**

```py
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image = cv2.resize(image, dsize=(227, 227))
# Tensorflow accepts RGB Format. So, No RGB to BGR Conversion.
image = image/255 # the reference model operates on images in [0,255] range instead of [0,1]
image = image[np.newaxis, ...] # Add one batch size
```

Please correct me, If I'm doing anything wrong here?